# Config My Domain To Point To My Windows Vps (No plesk or other software)

Tags: windows, dns, config, vps, nameservers

I have purchased this domain -> "**jsbales.com**" From **namecheap.com**

And this VPS (full **WINDOWS** vps, **no plesk or additional software**) from **CloudVPS.com**

I have **IIS** running on my vps and I can access my website using my IP (unique and private IP, I mean to say not shared or anything)

But I am having a real hard time making jsbales.com point to my IP. (you can use this ip as an example, 37.34.36.36)

I have only used hostings from paid shared hostings from companies like hostgator.com. In which case I could simply set the nameserver like ns1.hostgator.com etc...

But I don't get how I could config my domain to point to my vps.

Sorry for asking such a noob question but I've been googling from yesterday and haven't found any tutorial. Maybe I wasn't using the proper keyword.

Any help will be hugely beneficial.

Comment: This doesn't look like programming question. I think you should try to ask your question on Server Fault http://serverfault.com/.

Comment: I found some similar question in stack overflow. But none mentioned how to do it for windows server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you need to Create Your own DNS Server. Following article will help you for this :
[Windows VPS Quick Start Guide](https://manage.accuwebhosting.com/knowledgebase/874/Windows-VPS-Quick-Start-Guide.html)

This article explains entire process for starting with Windows VPS along with Creating Private Name Servers and Pointing your domain name to your VPS in easy steps.